# How to copy old version of file in mercurial to new location at tip?

Tags: mercurial

Have a C++ class whose .cpp has been heavily modified over several commits. Now it turns out we actually want a hierarchy, with the current implementation staying put and a different alteration of the original taking a new name.

How can I copy the original to a new name while keeping its history and without clobbering the changes I've made?

My first idea was to copy the file in a branch, then merge that branch into head, but mercurial is too clever and attempts to apply all changes to the copy as part of the merge, leading to massive conflicts.

Is there a different way I should be going about this? I don't know why mercurial things changes made to a file after it was copied should be applied to the copy...

Example to reproduce problem in bash:

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
hg init
echo hi > foo
hg add foo
hg commit
echo -e 'ho\nhi\nha' > foo
hg commit
hg up -r0
hg cp foo bar
echo 'howdy' >> bar
hg ci
hg up -r1
hg merge -r2 
# unexpected merge conflicts
```

Comment: You could use your branch method and then just do a hg revert -r 2 --all to deal with all conflicts.

Comment: Thanks! Can you add that as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use your branch method and then just do a

```
hg revert -r 2 --all
```

to deal with all conflicts.

Answer (score -1):

No need to branch and merge:

```
hg revert -rOLDREV FILENAME
hg cp FILENAME NEW_NAME
hg revert FILENAME
```

where OLDREV is the revision of the file FILENAME you want to copy to NEW_NAME.

Comment: That would give the copy the correct contents, but the copy would inherit the latest version history rather than branching off from the old version.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, exactly it would do that. But the new current version contains the old history at the same time. Thus this is takes the file, copies it and reverts all the unwanted additional changes - without any merge conflicts.

If that is not desirable, use the method as suggested by Tom in his comment: Create a new head with a copy branching at the old revision, then merge with the current head and revert the merged contents of the copy to the old version.

However I am surprised by hg's behaviour in this case. Changing it surely would be a regression, though.